# Django Regex match gives error

Tags: regex, django, url, url-routing

So I have a django project Where I trying to pass the following function named locate. I think I have figured the right query set. But I keep facing the following the following error.

```
NoReverseMatch at /incubators/1/

Reverse for 'locate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['locate/(?P<incubator_id>\\d+)/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/incubators/1/
Django Version:     1.11.3
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'locate' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['locate/(?P<incubator_id>\\d+)/$']

Exception Location:     C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  C:\Users\my dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.1
```

My views.py look something like this:

```
def details(request, incubator_id):
    inc = get_object_or_404(Incubators, pk = incubator_id)
    details = Details.objects.get(pk = incubator_id)
    return render(request, 'main/details.html', {'inc': inc, 'details': details})
def locate(request, incubator_id):
    pos = Incubators.objects.values_list('latt', 'lonn').filter(pk = incubator_id)
    return render(request, 'main/locate.html', {'pos': pos, 'incubator_id': incubator_id})
```

I am trying to pass the incubator_id as the primary key. Now I am preety sure the error is here below in my urls.py

```
url(r'location/', views.location, name = 'location'),
url(r'prediction/', views.prediction, name = 'prediction'),
url(r'incubators/(?P<incubator_id>[0-9]+)/', views.details, name = 'details'),      # shows details of incubators
url(r'^locate/(?P<incubator_id>\d+)/$', views.locate, name = 'locate'),
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. 
I have the following piece of code for calling the function

html file:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <a href="{% url "main:locate" incubator_id%}">Locate</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
```

Comment: You url config is fine - can you show us the code (or template fragment) that is calling `reverse`? That is where the problem is.

Comment: You need to supply an `incubator_id` to the locate view, which you are not doing in the `url` tag. You need to pass a second argument to the tag which contains the ID that the view is expecting.

Comment: how do I  another parameter? I have spacified incubator id in the regular expression.

Comment: `{% url "main:locate" insert_parameter_here %}` - your view requires that parameter, so you need to pass an ID when trying to generate the URL in your template.

Comment: So I tried "<a href="{% url "main:locate" incubator_id%}">Locate</a> ". Now it says: Reverse for 'locate' with arguments '('',)' not found

Comment: Do you have an `incubator_id` in the context? I think you're not yet seeing the point here. You need an `inubator_id` to be able to call that view. So you need to have one available (in the current view) that you can pass to this URL tag. Otherwise how does the view know which incubator you want to view?

Comment: @solarissmoke I think M preety close to solving the error. M I passing the right context ?

Comment: Your error says the error is occurring at `/incubators/1/`, but you haven't shown the URL pattern or view that handles that URL.

Comment: As an aside, you should make sure your regexes end with a dollar (apart from when you're using `include()`).